# 97 Yukon 5.7 Backfired with smoke inside the car, now idles really badly

Tags: exhaust, backfire, yukon

I have 1997 GMC Yukon. 5.7 litre. I started it this morning and it sounded like a gunshot. Smoke came into the vehicle and the PCV valve and one other sensor that plugs into the valve cover(s) were blown out.

I restarted and drove it. It runs but does not idle well.

What could be the problem? Is it a blown catalytic converter?